# Why does it add spaces between <variable>?

Tags: brackets

I want to do something like this:

```
<\phi>
```

But it looks erally weird, like there is a space before and after the variable inside the less than and equal than symbols. How can I make this look clean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<` and `>` are no brackets, but signs for bigger or smaller - if you want such brackets you can use `\rangle` and `\langle`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\langle\phi\rangle
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]